# Can the new “SCRAM-SHA-256” password authentication mechanism in Postgres 10 and later work with any JDBC drivers?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, jdbc, password

Postgres 10 added support for a new password authentication mechanism, [Salted Challenge Response Authentication Mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salted_Challenge_Response_Authentication_Mechanism) (SCRAM-SHA-256, see [RFC 7677](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7677)). [Discussed](https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-10-scram-authentication/) by Michael Paquier.

➥ Can this mechanism work with [JDBC drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver)?

If not, why not?

If so, have any drivers yet implemented this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not verified this myself, but the answer seems to be [Yes, from version 42.2.0](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/List_of_drivers) of the driver from the [jdbc.postgresql.org](https://jdbc.postgresql.org) project.

To quote the [changelog for Version 42.2.0](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html#version_42.2.0):

> Support SCRAM-SHA-256 for PostgreSQL 10 in the JDBC 4.2 version (Java 8+) using the Ongres SCRAM library.

See [GitHub pull request # 842](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/842).

That driver uses the [*SCRAM Java Implementation*](https://github.com/ongres/scram/) project by [ongres](https://github.com/ongres).